What tool is Zabbix using to send emails?
The latest version of Zabbix (v6.4) on Ubuntu LTS 22.04 works very well with email notification. In the interest of preventing redundancy, I would like to use that same package for sending emails from other non-Zabbix custom scripts on the same server. Does anyone know what Zabbix uses to send emails?
A "sudo apt list --installed" command on a working Zabbix server doesn't list postfix, sendmail, or any other mail program I am familiar with.

Zabbix has an internal email mechanism and uses JavaMail API for notifications. For better or for worse, Zabbix is not dependent on external mail transfer agents (MTAs) like Postfix or Sendmail.

Looks like I could write and compile a java script using JavaMail and call it from a shell script (e.g., https://tecadmin.net/sending-email-using-java-from-remote-smtp/) but it seems like overkill. I will likely just add another mail package. Thank you!

You're totally right! Going with a mail package is definitely the way to go – less hassle with all that JavaMail setup. I would suggest something like Apache Commons Email for something simple, or Spring Mail if you're into that.
